# how to define variable in footer

Tags: html, node.js, express, ejs

In the footer of my app (displayed on every page) I have a list of events, for example:

Next events:
name '''(course.name)'''
date '''(course.date)'''
I am creating a for loop

```
<h4 class="pb-1 pb-md-5">PROXIMOS EVENTOS</h4>
<% for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { %>
    <div class="eventDisplay text-center text-md-left">
        <p></p>
        <h6><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> <%= course.date%></h6>
        <p> <%= course.name %> </p>
        <p class="pFooter">Actualizate con nuestros</p>
        <a href="#">Saber mas <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
    </div>
<% }; %>
```

but I keep getting that course is not defined. How do I define course so everytime the user create a new course, I can pull that information and use it in my courses page AND my footer?

On the rendering side this is how it looks:

```
// ROOT ROUTE
// shows landing page
router.get("/", function(req, res){
// get all courses from DB
Course.find({}, function(err, allCourses){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        res.render("landing", {courses:allCourses});
    }
});
});
```

I am using EJS as engine.

Website is here: https://pure-cove-85477.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Can you show how you are rendering from your server's perspective?  I think there is supposed to be a `res.render("template-name.ejs", {foo: "bar"});` or something like that somewhere.  Considering [Using template engines with Express](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

Comment: hi, well I though that rendering my landing page which contains the footer as a partial template would work. I am using EJS, post updated

Comment: What is the value of `allCourses` before you render the landing page. Has the database returned the result of the query at this point and is it assigned to `allCourses` ?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an array of objects. `course` in not defined, so you have to use `courses` with index. Try this

```
<% for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { %>
    <div class="eventDisplay text-center text-md-left">
        <p></p>
        <h6><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> <%= courses[i].date%></h6>
        <p> <%= courses[i].name %> </p>
        <p class="pFooter">Actualizate con nuestros</p>
        <a href="#">Saber mas <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
    </div>
<% }; %>
```

If you want to use "course" in your ejs tags, you have to use a forEach loop. For example:

```
<% courses.forEach(course => { %>
    <div class="eventDisplay text-center text-md-left">
        <p></p>
        <h6><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i> <%= course.date%></h6>
        <p> <%= course.name %> </p>
        <p class="pFooter">Actualizate con nuestros</p>
        <a href="#">Saber mas <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></a>
    </div>
<% }); %>
```